# Showing thumbnails or some kind of preview in the Gnome workspace switcher popup?

Tags: gnome3, gnome-shell, workspaces

The workspace switcher popup doesn't provide previews by default. Is there any way to enable them? The Workspace List that shows up on the right when super key is pressed does have preview.

[image: switcher]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do that via a `gnome-shell` extension:

[*workspace-switcher-popup-thumbnails*](https://github.com/sustmi/gnome-shell-extension-workspace-switcher-popup-thumbnails)

Download [the zip file](https://github.com/sustmi/gnome-shell-extension-workspace-switcher-popup-thumbnails/archive/master.zip) and either use `gnome-tweak-tool` to install it or extract the archive and move the resulting directory to

```
~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/gnome-shell-extension-workspace-switcher-popup-thumbnails@sustmidown.centrum.cz
```

note the name of the extension directory (it has to match the `uuid` in `metadata.json`)
*then* inside that directory, edit the  `metadata.json` and replace `3.8` with your `gnome-shell` version, e.g.

```
"shell-version": ["3.18.2"]
```

save, restart both `gnome-shell` (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> then <kbd>r</kbd>) and  `gnome-tweak-tool` and use the latter to *enable* the extension:

[image]

Comment: Thanks, now coupled with https://github.com/bulletmark/libinput-gestures Gnome 3 on Arch is rocking.

Comment: I've been looking for exactly this for so long, but there are two problems: I use 9 workspaces in a 3x3 grid (using the extension ``Workspace Grid``) and I think this messes things up. I get a 9-box long column of workspaces on the far left of the screen that doesn't go away unless I restart gnome-shell. I *really* want something like this to work with my current grid!

Comment: @AmagicalFishy - well, I saw your Q but since I'm not familiar with _Workspace Grid_ I just skipped. It's not even clear from the Q (for someone like me, not familiar with that extension) whether showing thumbnails should just work or is a missing feature...

Comment: Extension no longer seems to work in gnome-shell 3.30.1

Comment: @ChrisBillington - no wonder, it hasn't been updated in five years.

Comment: While the extension still seems to work, and still seems to be maintained as of early 2019, @AmagicalFishy's concern remains valid and a recent [comment](https://github.com/sustmi/gnome-shell-extension-workspace-switcher-popup-thumbnails/issues/1#issuecomment-443557382) from the maintainer suggests that it's unlikely to be fixed anytime soon. Alternative solutions (might!) include [this extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1485/workspace-matrix/) or others mentioned in [this issue thread](https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid/issues/4) on the Workspace Grid page.