# How to change style of Gnome 3 workspace switcher/dock background?

Tags: gnome, gnome-shell

Since I've seen the following picture from this [/r/unixporn/ thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/unixporn/comments/5ddriu/gnome_after_a_few_hiccups_and_a_theme_breaking_x/) I got curious how to achieve such nice looking workspace dock style:

[image]

Knowing about how to achieve the grid switcher would be nice too, but I'm really more interested in the style, which I don't know whether it's provided builtin to the grid plugin or not.

I know of [workspace-grid-gnome-shell-extension](https://github.com/zakkak/workspace-grid-gnome-shell-extension), but it's not what provides that style, besides being incompatible with [workspace-switcher-popup-thumbnails](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243760/showing-thumbnails-or-some-kind-of-preview-in-the-gnome-workspace-switcher-popup), which I use and like already.

Specifically, knowing how to set background of the following region and making it transparent would be a start:

[image: screenshot]

I've asked on the reddit thread but got no response.

These are my current appearance settings:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out my problem at:

- https://github.com/passingthru67/workspaces-to-dock/issues/75

This is the patch I'm applying to `/usr/share/themes/Arc-Dark/gnome-shell/gnome-shell.css` for now (besides adopting the nice workspaces-to-dock):

```
@@ -1440,17 +1440,10 @@
 .workspace-thumbnails-left:rtl {
   visible-width: 40px;
   spacing: 11px;
-  padding: 12px; }
-
-.workspace-thumbnails,
-.workspace-thumbnails-left:rtl {
-  padding-right: 7px;
-  border-image: url("common-assets/dash/dash-right.svg") 9 9 9 9; }
-
-.workspace-thumbnails:rtl,
-.workspace-thumbnails-left {
-  padding-left: 7px;
-  border-image: url("common-assets/dash/dash-left.svg") 9 9 9 9; }
+  padding: 12px;
+  background-color: transparent;
+  border: 1px solid transparent rgba(82, 148, 226, 0.8);
+  border-radius: 1px; }

 .workspace-thumbnail-indicator {
   border: 4px solid rgba(82, 148, 226, 0.8);
```

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]