# Workspaces/Desktops thumbnails without gnome

Tags: desktop, software-rec, workspaces, alternatives

I've been trying Openbox and other window managers this week. I'm quite happy and committed to leaving Gnome DE behind.

There's one feature I'm missing though: I like the workspace preview popup that Gnome has by default. The virtual desktops thumbnails help me keep a stronger grasp on what windows are on which desktop.

I looked around but couldn't find an alternative.

> Maybe I lack the jargon?

**Would you please, recommend me alternatives to the workspace preview popup independent on the Gnome shell?**

Here's some links to posts with screenshots of the feature I'm looking for:

- [Post 1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/243760/showing-thumbnails-or-some-kind-of-preview-in-the-gnome-workspace-switcher-popup)
- [Post 2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/325256/how-to-change-style-of-gnome-3-workspace-switcher-dock-background)

Keywords I tried searching online:

- (Virtual workspace|workspace|desktop) (preview|thumbnail|miniature)